# how to get selected day's key in flutter calendar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a calendar and whenever I click on a day, I want to get the index(or key I'm not sure) of that day and add an event to it through a text form field? I want to create something like this library  which its name is `Table_calendar`

[image]

What is the best approach? If you need more information please let me know.
I have a function that will call when I click on a day. How can I use it
for putting an event on that?

Comment: On TableCalendar you have a property onDaySelected which is function who gets these parameters (DateTime day, List events, List holidays), source: https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar/example . Table calendar will trigger this function every time day is selected. Is this something you looking for?

Comment: actually i want to create a custom like that by myself

Comment: that will take a long time? because my calendar has differences with that , my calendar date is (jalali)

Comment: yeah that will take some time to be made, but that also depends on your experience and knowledge in Flutter. I think the best solution is to get a date when he click on day.